# Replacing some values of a column conditional on another column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I have a data-frame df:

```
ID   county state sales year
a     king   oh    10    2010
b      0     al    20    2011
c     kent   oh    10    2010
d      0     wa    30    2012
```

I want to replace the zero value of the county with county name conditional on ID, such that, if ID equals 'b', county will be 'anchorage' and for 'd' id county will be 'whitman'.

```
ID   county     state sales  year
a     king       oh    10    2010
b  anchorage     al    20    2011
c     kent       oh    10    2010
d  whitman       wa    30    2012
```

I applied the following code:

```
conditions = [(df['id'] == 'b'),(df['id'] == 'd')]
values = ['anchorage', 'whitman']
df['county'] = np.select(conditions, values)
```

The above code replaces the zero value with new value, but at the same time it turns existing nonzero county value to zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the default value of [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html#numpy-select) to the `'county'` column:

```
conditions = [(df['id'] == 'b'), (df['id'] == 'd')]
values = ['anchorage', 'whitman']
df['county'] = np.select(conditions, values, default=df['county'])
```

`df`:

```
  id     county state  sales  year
0  a       king    oh     10  2010
1  b  anchorage    al     20  2011
2  c       kent    oh     10  2010
3  d    whitman    wa     30  2012
```

Answer (score -1):

##### first create criteria and then simply use loc

```
condition = (df['country'] == 0)


for i in range(len(df['ID'])):
    if condition[i] == True:
        df.loc[df['ID'] == 'b', 'country'] = 'anchorage'
        df.loc[df['ID'] == 'd', 'country'] = 'whitman'
```

Comment: Two problems here: (1) the zero value in the first statement needs to be a string, as the input series is of `object` type. (2) the condition you are checking is useless as you proceed to change values across all rows where `ID` is `b` or `d`.